# Is it possible to open the content of a textarea in a about:blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to make a print button on my website.
Once the print button is clicked it should take the contents of the textarea and open it in a about:blank.

```
<textarea id="icontent" placeholder="Enter your content here." name="mas" rows="15" class="content">
</textarea>

<a id="wprint" class="btn">Print</a>
```

Is it possible to do this with only front end.

Comment: Do you just want the about blank because you want to print a specific portion of the page?

Comment: Save it and represent as a separate page. Or you could use iframe

Comment: @Adjit I would like the about:blank to open in a new tab and **ONLY** render the content a textarea. For an example <textarea><h1>HI</h1></textarea>. Then about:blank will show just "HI"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this. Add onclick="openBlank()" to your Print button:

```
<textarea id="icontent" placeholder="Enter your content here." name="mas" rows="15" class="content">
</textarea>

<a id="wprint" class="btn" onclick="openBlank()">Print</a>
```

Add a function in order to print the textarea's text into a blank page:

```
function openBlank()
{
   var text = document.getElementById("icontent").value;
   var myWindow = window.open('');
   myWindow.document.write(text);
}
```

Comment: small error: for a textarea, you want `.value` not `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

when you have no blocker try this

```
<script>
      output = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, inventore?'
      window.open().document.write(output)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `document.write` is to use a data URI. Incidentally this is also the only way to render content that isn't HTML (by changing `data:text/html,` to e.g. `data:text/plain,`).

The below snippet doesn't work because of Stack Overflow's content security settings, but you can see it in action on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4jkn0o6r/2/

```js
const button = document.getElementById('wprint');
const textarea = document.getElementById('icontent');

button.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  const data = encodeURIComponent(textarea.value);
  const doc = 'data:text/html,' + data;
  window.open(doc, '_blank');
});
```

```html
<textarea id="icontent">
<h1>Hello</h1>
</textarea>

<a id="wprint">Print</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest printing the text area to a `div` and then printing that specific `div`. Similar to the way StackOverflow shows you your textbox preview. Alternatively, if you don't want the user to see that, you can have a hidden `div` with the textbox information in it. Then you can easily open a new window to print that specific information.

```
var prtContent = document.getElementById("your div id");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
```

I don't believe this code works with printing the information inside a textbox, which is why I suggest you print the textbox input to a `div`